# Modifying and re-exporting an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, macos, nrf51

I'm setting up an embedded development system for the Nordic nrf51422 SoC in eclipse on my mac.  Nordic provides a c-based SDK for these chips as well as a closely related part, the nrf51822 in a single package.  I have a plugin that configures the proper dev environment for the '822 part on eclipse from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nrf51osx/?source=typ_redirect).

I'd like to modify this plugin to add project configuration settings for the '422; as the actual SDK includes libraries for this part, I believe all that is necessary is to add some stuff to the plugin's xml file and mess with the linker scripts a little.

I believe what I need to do is download the plugin directory, and then File->Import->Plug-ins and Fragments to import the downloaded directory it as a project, then make changes, re-export, and put the .jar it spits out into my dropins folder.

However, when I try to do this, the "Available Plug-ins and Fragments" field of the exporter is unpopulated.  I'm a complete eclipse newbie and don't have a good understanding of how this whole system works, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!  I've done some clicking around in the project preferences and everything seems to indicate that this is indeed a plug-in project, but I'm not familiar enough with the tool to know that I am looking in the right places...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Eclipse CDT (the C/C++ development tools) installed? The plugin has dependencies on CDT and if they are missing it might be stopping the export from showing the plugin, but I am just guessing here!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the Plugin Export wizard page it specifically excludes from the list plugins which were imported as 'Binary projects' and 'Binary projects with linked content'.

I assume this means there is something in this format of import which the export cannot deal with So you probably need the source code of the plugin to be able to proceed.

(Source of export page is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.exports.PluginExportWizardPage`)

Comment: Aw, rats.  Thanks for having a look for me, I would never have figured that out on my own!